# Generic range validation in c#

Tags: c#, generics, compare, range

I would like to have a generic range validator (not an aspnet control) that validates numbers.

```
T m_min;
T m_max;

bool Validate<T>(T obj)
{
    if (m_min > obj || obj > m_max)
```

I'm guessing **.CompareTo** is my best bet, restricting **T** with **IComparable**.

Would that work as intended or are there any catch?

"CompareTo" doesn't give me the good feeling the "operator >" does. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constraining your generic types to `IComparable` and using `CompareTo()` is the correct way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I know this response is over a year late, but just in case if someone is looking for the code.  Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10357393/532548).